# Run a bash script in cygwin using ./

Tags: bash, cygwin

I have a simple bash script that throw errors on a Windows machine in the Cygwin xterm terminal when I call it like so: `./myscript.bat`.  It runs fine when I call it like this: `/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/bash.exe myscript.bat`.  I am thinking that my shell is not using bash by default.  How can I set it to bash so that the next time I open the shell, I can execute my script using `./myscript.bat`?

Comment: *What* errors do you get? If you are actually naming bash scripts with a `.bat` extension, Cygwin may be running them with `cmd` (obviously not what you want).

Comment: You can find your default shell by doing `echo $0`. It should output `bash` if you are running it.

Comment: The `.bat` extension is commonly used for Windows batch files, not for bash scripts. Cygwin and bash don't care what extension you use, but I suggest either dropping the `.bat` or replacing it with either `.sh` or `.bash`.

Comment: Here is the error I was getting: C:\Workspace\myproj>find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print   | grep -v "^.$"   | xargs -I [] git --git-dir=[]/.git --work-tree=$PWD/[] pull origin master
fatal: Could not switch to '$PWD/./': No such file or directory
fatal: Could not switch to '$PWD/./': No such file or directory
fatal: Could not switch to '$PWD/./': No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a file, Windows (or some component within Windows) decides how to execute it based on the extension part of the file name.

Cygwin inherits this functionality, letting you run Windows commands from within Cygwin. Cygwin also implements most of the usual UNIX functionality (running commands based on their content), but the combination of UNIX and Windows semantics can't always be perfectly clean.

The `.bat` suffix refers to a Windows batch file, so when you try to execute `myscript.bat`, the system treats it that way rather than as a bash script.

Change the file name from `myscript.bat` to `myscript.bash` or `myscript.sh` -- or just drop the extension altogether (since someone running your script shouldn't need to care how it's written).

There are several other filename extensions you should avoid (like `.cmd`), depending on how Windows is configured. A few quick experiments show that a `.sh` extension is safe, but really you don't need to use an extension at all for a shell script.

And, as [R Sahu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23505720/827263) says, you also need to make sure the script has execute permission if you haven't already done so:

```
mv myscript.bat myscript
chmod +x myscript
```

Comment: That worked!  It was the extension that was the problem.  I removed it, and the script executed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to change permissions of the file to make it an executable.

Try

```
chmod +x myscript.bat
./myscript.bat
```